# WiX error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol Group:Users in section Fragment

Tags: installation, wix, wix3.5, usergroups

I am trying to add a new user in wix using the following component

```
<Component Id="NewUser" Guid="">
  <CreateFolder />
  <util:User Id="CIUSER" CreateUser="yes" UpdateIfExists="no" Name="ELASTICUSER" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" Password="eur1357">
     <util:GroupRef Id="Users" />
  </util:User>
</Component>
```

when I compile this code using candle though I am specifying `-ext WixUtilExtension` in the command line, I get the following error:

> error LGHT0094: Unresolved reference to symbol 'Group:Users' in
>   section 'Fragment:'

Could you please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a Group definition.

```
<util:Group Id="Users" Name="Users"/>

<Component Id="NewUser" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Guid="{0F8A5093-39EF-4F63-B7FA-A2931C21C865}">
  <CreateFolder />
  <util:User Id="CIUSER" CreateUser="yes" UpdateIfExists="no" Name="ELASTICUSER" PasswordNeverExpires="yes" Password="eur1357">
     <util:GroupRef Id="Users" />
  </util:User>
</Component>
```